# "Global" WinForms events

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have a few instances of a custom control that raise a custom event on MouseMove.
Here's the code:
EventArgs class:

```
public class GroupMoveEventArgs
{
    public enum Action { CalcOffset, Move };
    Action action;
    int mouse_x;
    int mouse_y;

    // setters missed here

    public GroupMoveEventArgs(GroupMoveEventArgs.Action action,
        int mouse_x, int mouse_y)
    {
        this.action = action;
        this.mouse_x = mouse_x;
        this.mouse_y = mouse_y;
    }
}
```

Control class:

```
public delegate void GroupMoveEventHandler(object sender, GroupMoveEventArgs e);
public event GroupMoveEventHandler GroupMoveEvent;

protected virtual void figureMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (mouseDown)
    {
        if (inGroup)
        {   // raising the event
            if (this.GroupMoveEvent != null)
                GroupMoveEvent(this, new GroupMoveEventArgs(
                               GroupMoveEventArgs.Action.Move,
                               Parent.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition).X,
                               Parent.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition).Y));
        }
    }
}

protected virtual void OnGroupMoveEvent(object sender, GroupMoveEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Got mouse move event " + this.num_of_points);
    if (inGroup)
    {
        if (e.EventAction == GroupMoveEventArgs.Action.Move)
        {
            Location = new Point(e.MouseX - offset.X, e.MouseY - offset.Y);
        }
        else
        if (e.EventAction == GroupMoveEventArgs.Action.CalcOffset)
        {
            Control c = sender as Control;
            Point pnt = Parent.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
            Point tmp = c.Location;
            offset.X = pnt.X - tmp.X;
            offset.Y = pnt.Y - tmp.Y;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I raise an event, it is handled only by the sender, when I need all the controls to handle it. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance, Ivan.

Comment: are all these controls in the same form?

Comment: Yes, they are on the same form.

Comment: Hard to see how, say, a textbox control could be interested in this event.  In general, the form should have an event handler for it and call a method on whatever control is interested in it.

Comment: I would expect your `GroupMoveEventArgs` class should be inheriting from `EventArgs` for consistency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

I would use a static event on the control

```
 public static event GroupMoveEventHandler GroupMoveEvent;
```

then your event handler would need to be static as well

```
 protected static virtual void 
                  OnGroupMoveEvent(object sender, GroupMoveEventArgs e)
 {
```

**Note**
As stated in the comments make sure you reference your static event like this

```
 GroupMoveEventHandler -= OnGroupMoveEvent;
```

here is an example of [Static Events](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/853a6a/static-event-in-C-Sharp/) if you want more info

**Option 2**

put your event handler in the form that contains the control and after making all your instance controls assign the single event handler that is in the form to the event on from the control

**In the form**

```
 Control c = new control();
 c.GroupMoveEventHandler += figureMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e);
```

public delegate void GroupMoveEventHandler(object sender, GroupMoveEventArgs e);
     public event GroupMoveEventHandler GroupMoveEvent;

```
 protected virtual void figureMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
     if (mouseDown)
     {
         if (inGroup)
         {   // raising the event
              if (this.GroupMoveEvent != null)
               GroupMoveEvent(this, new GroupMoveEventArgs(
                               GroupMoveEventArgs.Action.Move,
                               Parent.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition).X,
                               Parent.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition).Y));
         }
      }
    }
```

Comment: I thinnk this more or less covers it, if you need more help go ahead and ask.

Comment: Be *very* careful with static events, they have to be unsubscribed explicitly or they'll cause a leak.